# What is the difference between "followed by" and "is followed by"?

Tags: meaning, difference

What is the difference between these both sentences:

> Drought followed by Storm
>   Drought is followed by Storm

In both sentences which comes first and which follows it

Comment: Please give us the context.  That would help us help you!  It's not uncommon to see "drought" without an article, as a general concept; but "storm" is rarely used that way.  Also, I can't tell if your "storm" is capitalized on purpose or what.  It would really help us if we knew how you'd like to use your sentence.

Answer (score 5):

The difference between them would depend on context, but generally:

To my ear, the first describes something, like a time, an event or a place. Example: "Australia, a place of extreme and wild beauty, a land of drought followed by storm".

The second sounds more like a statement of fact. "Day is followed by night, pain is followed by joy, drought is followed by storm".

As for what comes first, 'followed by' indicates that the second item ('storm') comes after the first ('drought').

Answer (score 1):

As per me your first sentence means 
1)  Disaster happens because of “drought followed by storm.” (Indicative Statement)
2)  Every time disaster happens because of “drought is followed by storm.” ( Passive Voice)